# what is the easiest way to create a list of strings with the same suffix or prefix in python

Tags: python, string

In a shell, given I have 3 strings with the same prefix named `prefix_` and different suffix namely `1,2,3`, I can write `prefix_{1,2,3}` to get 3 strings.

I want to know if python has a similar syntax to do this job. I want to make these strings a list and iterate over it.

Is there any solution ??

I surely don't want to write it like `alist=['prefix_1','prefix_2','prefix_3']` lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for this.

```py
new_array = [f"prefix_{i}" for i in old_array]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
alist=['prefix_'+str(i) for i in range(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The shell expansion notation is equivalent to a product, you can achieve the same with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and `str.join`.

shell:

```
$ echo {a,b}x{1,2,3}
ax1 ax2 ax3 bx1 bx2 bx3
```

python:

```
from itertools import product
list(map(''.join, product(['a', 'b'], 'x', ['1', '2', '3'])))
```

output: `['ax1', 'ax2', 'ax3', 'bx1', 'bx2', 'bx3']`